# Selection Sort function working sorting incorrectly

Tags: c, selection-sort

I am trying to implement my first sorting algorithm in C, where an array of numbers is given as a command-line argument before a function is called to sort the array and print the output. The program re-prints the array before sorting it, so as far as I can tell the error is in the sorting algorithm itself. Here is the function:

```
    void ascending(int n, int arr[])
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < (n - 1); i++)
        {
           //min is equal to i (use as index)
           int min = i;

            //Compare arr[i] to all other elements in the array
            for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
            {
                //If a smaller number is found, its index (j) is now min
                if (arr[j] < arr[min])
                {
                    min = j;

                    //Swapping values to be in correct place
                    int temp = arr[min];
                    arr[min] = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

        printf("sorted: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            printf("%i, ", arr[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

If I ask it to sort [5, 4, 60, 2, 1] it will correctly sort the output to sorted: [1, 2, 4, 5, 60]

But if I ask it to sort [60, 5, 3, 3, 1, 4, 2] it will print: [2, 1, 4, 3, 3, 5, 60], sorting some numbers but not others.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What did you do after finding out the program doesn't work? Did you then go ahead and debug it? Run your program in a debugger and trace its flow and variable values as it runs. If you have already done that then please provide the debugging info you have found. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [Selection Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort), the goal of the inner `for` loop is to find the index of the minimum element in the un-sorted subarray (i.e., the array starting at index `i` and ending at index `n-1`).  The swap should occur after you have found the min value, so that it is correctly placed at index `i` in the array:

```
void ascending(int n, int arr[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < (n - 1); i++)
    {
       //min is equal to i (use as index)
       int min = i;

       //Compare arr[i] to all other elements in the array
       for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
       {
           //If a smaller number is found, its index (j) is now min
           if (arr[j] < arr[min])
           {
               min = j;
           }
       }

       //Swapping values to be in correct place
       int temp = arr[min];
       arr[min] = arr[i];
       arr[i] = temp;
    }
    printf("sorted: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%i, ", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, pretty obvious now but I was having a major mind-blank last night. Have a good day!

Answer (score 2):

In this if statement

```
           if (arr[j] < arr[min])
            {
                min = j;

                //Swapping values to be in correct place
                int temp = arr[min];
                arr[min] = arr[i];
                arr[i] = temp;
            }
```

after the assignment

```
                min = j;
```

this swapping

```
                //Swapping values to be in correct place
                int temp = arr[min];
                arr[min] = arr[i];
                arr[i] = temp;
```

does not make a sense.

The inner for loop can be written the following way

```
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            //If a smaller number is found, its index (j) is now min
            if (arr[j] < arr[min])
            {
                min = j;
            }
        }

        if ( min != i )
        {   
                //Swapping values to be in correct place
                int temp = arr[min];
                arr[min] = arr[i];
                arr[i] = temp;
        }
```

Pay attention to that it is better to declare the function the way when the first parameter specifies the array and the second parameter specifies the number elements in the array,

For example

```
void ascending( int arr[], size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        size_t min = i;

        for ( size_t j = i + 1; j < n; j++ )
        {
            if ( arr[j] < arr[min] ) min = j;
        }

        if ( min != i )
        {
            int tmp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[min];
            arr[min] = tmp;
        }
    }
}
```